# EXECUTE IMMEDIATE not working with INSERT in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to run this following code:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "INSERT INTO `bombora_surge.company_intent_history` (RowKey,?) VALUES ('sample',?)" USING "1",2;
```

But I am continuously getting the following error:

```
Invalid EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql string `INSERT INTO `bombora_surge.company_intent_history` (RowKey,?) VALUES ('sample',?)`, Syntax error: Unexpected "?" at [1:19]
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Why are you giving a `?` as a column name, as in `(RowKey,?)`?

Comment: you need to back-quote the `?` like `(RowKey, \`?\`)` if you want to use `1` as a column name.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a wiki for a better visibility for the community:

as @Jaytiger suggests you can use back-quote for the question mark symbol as it will recognise it as a column name and not as a place holder for execute immediate.

> you need to back-quote the ? like (RowKey, `?`) if you want to use 1 as a column name.

Good reference:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate